# Inner join con tres tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, join

Necesito hacer en una sola consulta tres inner join, mi código funciona si escribo esto:

```
SELECT * FROM competenciaCombate inner join concursante where concursante.id_conc=competenciaCombate.ganador_comb
```

Pero me hace falta añadir otros dos inner join que serían:

```
inner join concursante where concursante.id_conc=competenciaCombate.id_conc1
inner join concursante where concursante.id_conc=competenciaCombate.id_conc2
```

Este es el código que intento escribir en sql

```
SELECT * FROM competenciaCombate 
inner join concursante 
where concursante.id_conc=competenciaCombate.ganador_comb 
inner join concursante 
where concursante.id_conc=competenciaCombate.id_conc1 
inner join concursante 
where concursante.id_conc=competenciaCombate.id_conc2
```

No sé si tenga un error de sintaxis u otra cosa, de antemano, muchas gracias.

El error que me da al usar esta consulta es:

> MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join concursante where
>   concursante.id_conc=competenciaCombate.id_conc1 inn' at line 1

Comment: Cuando pruebas la consulta, ¿qué sucede?

Comment: Me marca este error 

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join concursante where concursante.id_conc=competenciaCombate.id_conc1 inn' at line 1

Comment: Estas indicando cuales campos vas a relacionar en tus tablas correctamente, pero la palabra que se utiliza es 'on' y tu estas poniendo 'where', cambia esas palabras y debería de funcionar

Answer (score 2):

La sintaxis que estás utilizando es incorrecta. No se hace a través de la palabra *where* (la cual se utiliza para filtrar tus resultados) sino a través de la palabra *on*, así:

```
SELECT * FROM competenciaCombate 
INNER JOIN concursante 
ON concursante.id_conc = competenciaCombate.ganador_comb 
INNER JOIN concursante 
ON concursante.id_conc = competenciaCombate.id_conc1 
INNER JOIN concursante 
ON concursante.id_conc =competenciaCombate.id_conc2
```

Comprueba si necesitas además aplicarle un filtro (con *where*, tal y como te comentaba al principio).

Viendo además que utilizas el join siempre a la misma tabla, es posible que esta consulta también te sirva:

```
SELECT * FROM competenciaCombate 
INNER JOIN concursante 
ON concursante.id_conc = competenciaCombate.ganador_comb 
   AND concursante.id_conc = competenciaCombate.id_conc1 
   AND concursante.id_conc =competenciaCombate.id_conc2
```

o bien, utilizar esas mismas condiciones en el where:

```
SELECT * FROM competenciaCombate 
INNER JOIN concursante 
ON concursante.id_conc = competenciaCombate.ganador_comb 
WHERE concursante.id_conc = competenciaCombate.id_conc1 
      AND concursante.id_conc =competenciaCombate.id_conc2
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Debes hacer el uso de `ON` en tu [`INNER JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) y agregar un `WHERE` en lugar de los otros `INNER JOIN` que intentas hacer, ya que es la misma tabla que ya uniste:

---

```
SELECT * FROM competenciaCombate
INNER JOIN concursante ON concursante.id_conc=competenciaCombate.ganador_comb
WHERE concursante.id_conc=competenciaCombate.id_conc1 
AND concursante.id_conc=competenciaCombate.id_conc2
```